# Executable symbolic link file not working

Tags: bash, filenames, quoting

On Mac OSX, I am having trouble with a pretty simple thing. My symbolic link doesn't want to execute. Can you help me spot the trouble? Thanks!

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ ls -l /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
total 320
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 pitosalas  admin  160688 Jun 27 00:27 subl

$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport//bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/subl

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/subl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 pitosalas  admin  63 Jul  1 16:36 /usr/local/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

$ subl
-bash: subl: command not found
```

#### Response to comment:

What rehash? You don't mean rbenv rehash do you? Also here's the command in a new shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/subl
```

-bash: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you either run `rehash` and try again, or open a new shell and try it there? Also, does it work if you enter the full path, `/usr/local/bin/subl`?

Comment: Just for completeness: I meant to say `hash -r` instead of `rehash` (which is for csh-likes). This will tell your shell to scan the PATH for executables, though I think bash does this automatically on 'command not found' anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `\` from your `ln` command if you're using quotation marks:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

(There was also a double `/` before bin, but that doesn't actually prevent the OS from finding the file, and it looks like it got removed anyway.)

Comment: @pitosalas it is generally a good idea to build your command lines using tab-expansion when possible. Just start writing a path and hit tab to see the completions. That way, you _know_ you have the right path.

Comment: @terdon: I do... But that was what got me in trouble! On Mac, when I tab expand a path containing a space in a directory name, even with a quote, it inserts the backslash to escape the space!

Comment: @pitosalas yes, but if the shell escapes everything it needs to escape, you no longer need to quote the path. My point is you _either_ build the path with tab expansion, _or_ you quote it in which case you should not escape characters because they are already quoted.